# How to iterate through hidden divs and scrape text?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website with expandable divs that hide text within it, which I am trying to scrape. I can only scrape the text in the first expandable div. However, I can click through all divs. How can I scrape text from all divs?

Closed HTML:

```
<li class="views-row views-row-1 pub1 default-on clk" tabindex="150">  
          <div class="teaser Speeches col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 crop2" data-nid="50849" data-tid="6971" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="thumb" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="/sites/pm/files/styles/news_listing_square/public/default_news/20180501_default_news2.jpg?itok=a1pfZTOA" alt="" title=""></div>
  <div class="news-teaser">
    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    <div class="body">TEASER TEXT</div>
    <div class="category">Speeches<br>PLACE <span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2019-06-10T18:15:00-04:00">June 10, 2019</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sticky0"></div>
<div class="full-article" aria-hidden="true"></div>  
</li>
<li class="views-row views-row-2 pub1 default-on clk" tabindex="150"> </li>
<li class="views-row views-row-3 pub1 default-on clk" tabindex="150"> </li>
```

When item is clicked and full speech can be seen:

```
<li class="views-row views-row-1 pub1 default-on clk active" tabindex="150">     
          <div class="news-article-body-fields">    
          <h1 class="field-content">TITLE</h1>    
              
          <div class="image col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 news-image-caption">
<span class="caption"></span>
</div>    
          <span class="field-content Speeches-news-article-date"><div class="inline-date">
  PLACE <span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2019-06-10T18:15:00-04:00">June 10, 2019</span>
</div></span>    
  <div class="views-field views-field-body">        <p><span lang="EN-CA" xml:lang="EN-CA">CHECK AGAINST DELIVERY</span></p><p><span lang="EN-CA" xml:lang="EN-CA">Good morning, everyone. </span></p><p><span lang="EN-CA" xml:lang="EN-CA">Before we get into things, I want to take a second to thank ____ – for his introduction, yes, but more importantly, for his leadership. </p> SPEECHES CONTINUE IN <P> TAGS.
```

Here is my Python script:

```py
# Libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import requests
import time

# Opening up connection and grabbing HTML file via Chrome
url = 'https://pm.gc.ca/eng/news/speeches'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

# Delaying scrapper to prevent scraper from closing too soon
browser.implicitly_wait(2)

# Creating loop to open up all divs with same class name
article_list = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".views-row.pub1.default-on.clk")

# All titles for expanded divs printed. Works!
for article in article_list:
    print(article.text)


# Only works for first article in list
for article in article_list:
    article.click()
    
    time.sleep(3)
    
    # Getting title
    title = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@class = 'field-content']")
    print(title.text)   

    # Getting date
    date = browser.find_element_by_class_name("date-display-single")
    print(date.text)

    # Getting place
    place = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'inline-date']")
    print(place.text)

    # Getting speech
    speech_div = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@lang = 'EN-CA']")
    
    for p in speech_div:
        print(p.text)
```

Currently, I can scrape the whole speech for the very first article. The driver then clicks to the second speech in the next expandable div, outputs a whole bunch of blank space, and continues on to the next few speeches in the same fashion as the second speech (whole bunch of blank space).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speech details are loaded using an AJAX request. This means you don't even have to use selenium for this, `requests` alone is enough, which speeds up things quite a bit:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent':  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'
}


def make_soup(url: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    res.raise_for_status()
    return BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')


def fetch_speech_details(speech_id: str) -> str:
    url = f'https://pm.gc.ca/eng/views/ajax?view_name=news_article&view_display_id=block&view_args={speech_id}'
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    res.raise_for_status()
    data = res.json()
    html = data[1]['data']
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    body = soup.select_one('.views-field-body')
    return str(body)


def scrape_speeches(soup: BeautifulSoup) -> dict:
    speeches = []
    for teaser in soup.select('.teaser'):
        title = teaser.select_one('.title').text.strip()
        speech_id = teaser['data-nid']
        speech_html = fetch_speech_details(speech_id)
        s = {
            'title': title,
            'details': speech_html
        }
        speeches.append(s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'https://pm.gc.ca/eng/news/speeches'
    soup = make_soup(url)
    speeches = scrape_speeches(soup)
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(speeches)
```

output:

```
[
    {'title': 'PM remarks for Lunar Gateway', 'details': '<div class="views-field views-field-body"> <p>CHECK AGAINST DELIVERY</p><p>Hello everyone!</p><p>I’m delighted to be here at the Canadian Space Agency to share some great news with Canadians.</p><p>I’d like to start by thanking the President of the Agency, Sylvain Laporte ... },
    {...},
    ....
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just a few modifications: 1. In the fetch_speech_details function, there is a random 'f' in front of the url. 2. You have to do the following after you declare the url: `url = url.format(speech_id = speech_id)`. 3. You forgot to return the speeches in the scrape_speeches function. Asides from that, a huge thank you.  Also, I have two more follow-up questions: 1. How did you know that this was AJAX and how did you find the AJAX string. 2. How can I remove all the tags on the 'details'. 3. Should I still use selenium to implement infinite scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

You need to scope the search to the current div, rather than the whole document. Call `find*` on the current element (`article` rather than `browser`):

```
title = article.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@class = 'field-content']")
speech_div = article.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@lang = 'EN-CA']")
```